# Get click event within slidejs pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidesjs

I have a slidejs slide show that uses 3 images, when you click on an image it changes text in a slide container.

Example Code:

```
<a href="#">
 <div class="col-md-12">
 <div class="quote">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $al_options['al_conimg'] ?>" alt="quote"/>
           <p class="profile_text"><?php echo $al_options['al_scon'] ?> <br />
               <a href="<?php echo $al_options['al_teamct1_url1']; ?><?php echo $al_options['al_teamct1_url_element']; ?>">More Info</a> 
 </div> 
     </div>
</a>
```

Notice the a href='#'" tags. What i need is to add a button or link to open a url. jQuery or js is ok. When I add a href to try to do this it is ignored, and the click is picking up http://url.com/#. Basically is there away to have a href within a href to open a page?

Comment: I don't see any other `href` tag in your code..? `$('.col-md-4 > a').click(function(){ window.location = $(this).prop('href') });`

Comment: Well, yeah, of course it won't work, you've changed your code completely from what you showed originally. Soo..now it's, `$('.profile_text > a').click(function(){ window.location = $(this).prop('href') });` Furthermore, note that if the `anchor` tag doesn't have `display:block` then likely it won't consume the available space of the parent and you must click specifically on each letter.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with the code above. when adding the second href, it broke the functionality of the pagination. I just added a form button, and used the action to open the page. Thanks for trying.